# How to replace for-loops with matrix-operations?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, matrix, indexing

```
for x in range(0, width):
    for y in range(0, width):
        D[x,y] = dist(A[x,y], B[x,y])

def dist(a, b):
    return ((a-b)**2).sum()
```

Values in A and B are matrices of shape (3,3)

How can I achieve the same result using matrix operations instead of for-loops?
The following code does not work.

```
D[[range(0,height)],[range(0,width)]] = dist(A[[range(0,height)],[range(0,width)], 
                                             B[[range(0,height)],[range(0,width)])]
```

Comment: Please provide your `dist` code and `A` & `B` values. There's no "generic" answers for vectorization

Comment: Could you please show the code of `dist`? In general just writing `d = dist(a, b)` should be enough, to vectorize the calculations.

Comment: does this help?

Comment: Look into Scipy cdist.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of this is that `A` and `B` are both NumPy arrays with dimensions h*w*3*3.

The simplest way to use array operations to find the squared distance between the 3-by-3 matrices `A[i,j,:,:]` and `B[i,j,:,:]` for each `i,j` is then to write:

```
distances = np.sum((A-B)**2, axis=(2,3))
```

i.e. just squaring everything and summing over the last two axes.

This involves the creation of some unnecessary temporary arrays (`A-B`, then its square), so if you need *extreme* efficiency, you could use another option like a Numba jitted for loop that runs `np.vdot` for each pair of `A[i,j,:,:]` and `B[i,j,:,:]`. But it is unlikely this is your bottleneck.